# Variable scope inside IIFE

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

i'm kind of new with JS. So forgive me if the question is too naive.

I'm working with an IIFE like this:

```
var App = (function() {

    var test = '';

    var init = function() {
        App.test = 'test';
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };

})();
```

Why is App.test exposed if i'm not returning it? I thought only returned variables will be exposed (like App.init). And also, how can I set the value of App.test without exposing it?

By exposing it i mean to be accesible outside the IIFE (ie: console of browser)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because `App.test` is a *property*, not a *variable*!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `App.test` property is not the same as the local variable `test` in that anonymous function. It's just a property of the App object that is created when you call `App.init()`.

On any object, code can generally create properties at will, so you can also do something like

```
App.favoriteColor = "blue";
```

Now, if what you're trying to do is keep that `test` variable in the closure around as a private data store, then your `init()` function should just refer to it directly instead of referring to a property of the "App" object:

```
var init = function() {
  test = 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Once you run `App.init()`, `App.test` will have a value because you are declaring its value here `App.test = 'test';`. I'm guessing you want to keep this a private variable so you may want to do this instead:

```
var App = (function() {

    var test = '';//this is private

    var init = function() {
        test = 'test';//private variable now!
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Marked the first one as correct beacuse came in first.